# Boto3 - sqs get_queue_url results in QueueDoesNotExist

Tags: boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to read from an SQS queue. In order to do so, I need to get the queue url. this is my code

```
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    print('running as:')
    pp.pprint(sts.get_caller_identity())

    sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
    queue_name = settings.SQS_JOBS_TASK_RESULTS_QUEUE
    print('getting queue_name: ', queue_name)
    res = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=queue_name)
```

From the code above you can see I'm also verifying my identity.

sqs.get_queue_url always fails with

> botocore.errorfactory.QueueDoesNotExist: An error occurred (AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue) when calling the GetQueueUrl operation: The specified queue does not exist or you do not have access to it.

i have copy pasted the queue name from the aws web console. still fails.

I know that my permissions are ok because if i skip this step, copy paste the url from the web console and jump directly to reading and writing the queue, it works.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As I was writing this question i got the light bulb that maybe there is a specific permission for getting the queue url.

lo and behold, make sure you don't forget to add `sqs:GetQueueUrl` in your policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:DeleteMessageBatch",
                "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:xxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: is this a little too open? from my understanding, you are letting anyone call those actions on the queue xxxxxxxxx

Comment: no. because this is a policy attached to an IAM role/user/group.